# Joomla templates creation, version compatibility

Tags: templates, joomla

I want to start creating Joomla templates from scratch. I've found some courses and tutorials online about the subject, like Lynda.com's Joomla 1.6 Creating and Editing Templates.

My question is, if I study tutorials that show how to create templates for older versions of Joomla (like 1.6) would they be compatible with 2.5 or in other words, has the structure changed from 1.6 to 2.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla 1.6, 1.7 and 2.5 coding standards are the same, however 2.5 has more features than the previous versions. So to answer your question, yes, if you create a template for Joomla 1.6, it will be compatible on 2.5 aswell.

Comment: thank you! after a lot of search and asking on forums I'm now convinced that all is well on the subject :)